# TypeError: moment is not a function - Angularjs Jasmine Test Case

Tags: unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I'm getting an issue when writing test cases for my controller in AngularJs.

Reason I have found : When i initialize the moment in my constructor I'm getting this error while running the test cases.

I'm sharing my controller code as well as test file.

```
  class contractCancellationCtrl {
    constructor(
            moment) {
  'ngInject';
  this.moment = moment;
  this.minSalesDate = moment().subtract(1, 'months').date(1);

  }
```

```js
define(['contract'], () => {
  'use strict';

  let momentMock,
      ctrl,
      $q,
      $scope;
  
  const dateMock = "Feb 16, 2018 10:22 AM";

  fdescribe('contractCancellation', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
      module('nse.contract');

      momentMock = jasmine.createSpyObj('moment', ['subtract']);
      momentMock.subtract.and.returnValue(dateMock);

      inject((_$rootScope_, _$controller_, _$q_) => {
        $scope = _$rootScope_.$new();
        $q = _$q_;
        ctrl = _$controller_('contractCancellationCtrl as contractCancellationCtrl', {
          moment: momentMock,
        });
      });

      contractCancellationDeferred = $q.defer();
    });

    it('should expect the controller to be initialized', () => {
      expect(ctrl.moment).toEqual(momentMock);

    });
  });
});
```